# Quarteroni Theorem 5.6: convergence of power method for eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

The theorem is stated as follows:

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a diagonalizable matrix whose eigenvalues satisfy

$|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|\geq |\lambda_3|\geq \cdots\geq |\lambda_n|$.

Assuming that $\alpha_1\neq 0$, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that

$||\hat{q}^{(k)}-x_1||\leq C\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^k$

where $\hat{q}^{(k)}=\dfrac{q^{(k)}||A^kq^{(0)}||_2}{\alpha_1\lambda^k_1}=x_1+\sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^kx_i$, $k=1,2,...$

Also: we assume $Ax_i=\lambda_ix_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$.

They then normalize each $x_i$ and give the following argument:

$||x_1+\sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^kx_i-x_1||_2=||\sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^kx_i||_2\overset{*}{\leq}\bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n (\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1})^2(\dfrac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1})^{2k}\bigg)^{1/2}\leq \bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^k\bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n (\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1})^2\bigg)^{1/2}$

My concern lies in the $(*)$ inequality. Unless we assume $A$ is normal, and therefore unitarily diagonalizable, I don't see how this inequality is true. It seems like the best we can say is in fact:

$||\sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^kx_i||_2\leq \sum_{i=2}^n \bigg|\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|\,\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^k\,||x_i||_2\leq \bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n \bigg|\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|^2\,\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^{2k}\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n||x_i||_2^2\bigg)^{1/2}$.

The last inequality following from Cauchy-Schwarz. So the final bound should really be

$\bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n \bigg|\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|^2\,\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^{2k}\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n||x_i||_2^2\bigg)^{1/2}\leq \bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n \bigg|\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|^2\,\bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^{2k}\bigg)^{1/2}(n-1)^{1/2}\leq \bigg|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\bigg|^k\bigg(\sum_{i=2}^n \bigg|\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\bigg|^2\bigg)^{1/2}(n-1)^{1/2}$.

Am I misunderstanding something? Or is there just an error in the text?

Comment: The first part of it says "Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a diagonalizable matrix." . It implies it is normal.

Comment: Diagonalizable does not imply unitarily diagonalizable though?